# Cumulative (Running) Total in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, cumulative-sum

I have this query for my database

```
SELECT FlightNumber, FlightTime FROM flight_log
```

which outputs the Flight Number and the Flight Time:

| Flight Number | FlightTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |

I am wondering if there is a way to add a cumulative total to the end of that so I receive the output:

| FlightNumber | FlightTime | CumulativeTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | 2 | 10 |
| 4 | 4 | 14 |

The columns are titled `FlightNumber` and `FlightTime`, and the table is called `Flight_log`.
Help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `SUM()` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT FlightNumber, FlightTime,
       SUM(FlightTime) OVER (ORDER BY FlightNumber) AS CumulativeTotal
FROM flight_log
ORDER BY FlightNumber;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can use a correlated subquery:

```sql
SELECT FlightNumber, FlightTime,
       (SELECT SUM(f2.FlightTime)
        FROM flight_log f2
        WHERE f2.FlightNumber <= f1.FlightNumber) AS CumulativeTotal
FROM flight_log f1
ORDER BY FlightNumber;
```